# Code completion for CodeBlocks c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, autocomplete, codeblocks

So i wanted to ask how to get "proper" Code Completion working for  CodeBlocks 13.12 for c++, im running mint rosa at the moment.

By this i mean

```
string buf;
buf.                     <--This doesnt work - no suggestions
```

I would like the "." to show me relevant function/attribute names. It autocompletes variables and shows relevant type information, but nothing of the type mentioned above that originates from a ***library***.

For example I see that this works for some cases

```
MyClass obj;
obj.                     <--This works
```

Comment: You should probably ask the Code::Blocks people rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: I thought i'd ask here since its half working, might be a setting of some sort

Comment: I have 13.12 for Ubuntu and buf.   works as expected.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, so its just a matter of a check box somewhere